# Wordpress updating Script n Styles Extension Script does not work

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Thanks in advance for any help provided guys.

I have a wordpress Script n styles extension on my wordpress, the previous developer added it. 
However I noticed that when I update my script in "Script n Styles", that does not change anything.
Without cache, with cache, refreshing as many times as you want, switching navigators it does not update the script stays the same.

Just take a look: 
[Script n Styles extension's script here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIhxk.png)

[Script displayed on the page whatever I do in script n style extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt3aW.png)

Do you have any ideas where that could come from ? I can send the link of that website if you want! Its afh.asso.fr (the home page only uses that bit of code (its for the "mon afh" little red button on the home page)

Thanks in advance for your help guys, it is really appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles');

function theme_enqueue_styles() {

    // Get the theme data
    $the_theme = wp_get_theme();

   // Add custom style here in custom.css
    wp_enqueue_style('custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.css', array(), $the_theme->get('Version'));


     wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

     // add custom javascript here in custom.js
     wp_enqueue_script('main', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array(), $the_theme->get('Version'), true);

}
```

Can find more information here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where should I add this bit of code?

Comment: @julienstack in functions.php file in theme folder